# How do I solve $\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i- \overline{X}_n)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X and Y be two random variables and let ${(x_1,y_1)},...{(x_n,y_n)}$ be an i.i.d. sample of n observations from the joint distribution of X and Y. You know that the sample average of X is $\overline{X}_n$ = 4, each X and Y have a sample variance equal to 2 (i.e. $s_x^2 = s_y^2$ =2) and that the sample correlation coefficient of X and Y is $R_{x,y}$ = -0.25. Compute the following quantities. Justify your answer?

How do I solve $\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i- \overline{X}_n)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline X_n)=\frac1n\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-n\overline X_n\Bigr)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\overline X_n=\overline X_n-\overline X_n=0.
$$

Comment: How do you get the n in front of $\overline {X}_n$ in step two?

Comment: @Ayoshna We have that $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\sum_{i=1}^n\overline X_n$, but $\overline X_n$ does not depend on $i$. Hence, $\sum_{i=1}^n\overline X_n=n\overline X_n$ since there are $n$ terms in this sum (all terms are equal to $\overline X_n$).